# Histogram which do not use bin intervals but concrete values

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I've hacked up following code, it is basically histogram which does not use interval bins. It is useful for discrete values. I've done it in pure numpy:

```
In [281]: a = np.array([1,2,5,3,2])

In [282]: hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(a, bins = np.arange(np.amin(a), np.amax(a) + 2))

In [283]: freq = hist

In [284]: nums = bin_edges[1:] - 1

In [285]: matrix = np.transpose((nums, freq))

In [286]: matrix[matrix[:,1]!=0]
Out[286]:
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 1],
       [5, 1]])
```

Questions:

1. Is there more easy and more efficient way compared to my code?
2. How can I do the same but also for decimal values? I suppose whole trick will be in `np.arrange` function. Basically I need the histogram which will not use intervals but concrete values e.g. following input:

   1.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2, 5, 8, 9, 2.3, 1.2

should return following output:

```
[1.2, 2],
[2, 1],
[2.3, 2],
[2.4, 1],
[5, 1],
[8, 1],
[9, 1],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter([1,2,5,3,2])
>>> counter[1]
1
```

Similarly,

```
>>> counter = Counter([1.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2, 5, 8, 9, 2.3, 1.2])
>>> counter[1.2]
2
```

Use Counter.items() to get your key-value pairs:

```
>>> counter.items()
[(2, 1), (5, 1), (8, 1), (2.4, 1), (1.2, 2), (9, 1), (2.3, 2)]
```

If you want to change them to list of lists instead of list of tuples for some reason:

```
>>> map(list, counter.items())
[[2, 1], [5, 1], [8, 1], [2.4, 1], [1.2, 2], [9, 1], [2.3, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems the most simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

For an array of integers, you can use [`numpy.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html).

For example,

```
In [59]: a = np.array([1,2,5,3,2])

In [60]: np.bincount(a)
Out[60]: array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1])
```

The return value is an array of counts of values from 0 up to the maximum found in the input.

For the array of floating point values, you can use [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the argument `return_counts=True` (if you are using numpy version 1.9 or later).

For example,

```
In [64]: b = [1.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2, 5, 8, 9, 2.3, 1.2]

In [65]: values, counts = np.unique(b, return_counts=True)

In [66]: values
Out[66]: array([ 1.2,  2. ,  2.3,  2.4,  5. ,  8. ,  9. ])

In [67]: counts
Out[67]: array([2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Be aware, though, that this uses equality comparsion of floating point values, which can cause some surprising results because of normal floating point imprecision:

```
In [98]: c = [0.1+0.2, 0.3]

In [99]: np.unique(c, return_counts=True)
Out[99]: (array([ 0.3,  0.3]), array([1, 1]))
```

Look at `c` to see what happened:

```
In [100]: c
Out[100]: [0.30000000000000004, 0.3]
```

Comment: Thank you, does this have some advantage compared to @Sait solution?